# Specifying deferred action before IQueryable has been evaluated

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I would like to perform some post-processing on an entity that is returned from an `IQueryable`, but I would like to specify that post-processing *before* evaluating the query. So for example:

```
IQueryable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return _context.Set<Client>()
        .PostProcess(c => c.MobileNumber = c.MobileNumber.Replace(" ", ""));
}

Client GetClient(int id)
{
    return GetClients()
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
}
```

In the above example I would want every `Client` returned from the above two methods to have all spaces removed from their mobile number. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

## Edit: This is a bad idea

It works in the simple case stated in the OP, but any further `IQueryable` extensions (such as a `.Where()` clause) will discard the post-processing behaviour. I'm not sure it's technically possible to do what I want to do, and now I come to think of it I'm not even sure what the semantics would be beyond the simple case. Still, the simple case works and is quite handy to keep things fluent...

---

## Original:

I thought I would share my approach for this in case someone finds it useful (or has a comment on why it's a bad idea). The solution uses two decorators to defer the post-processing action until the query is executed, and an extension method to set them up:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> PostProcess<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Action<T> postProcessor) where T : class
    {
        return new QueryableWrapper<T>(source, postProcessor);
    }

    // wraps IQueryProvider.Execute methods with post-processing action
    class QueryProviderWrapper<T> : IQueryProvider where T : class
    {
        private readonly IQueryProvider _wrapped;
        private readonly Action<T> _postProcessor;

        public QueryProviderWrapper(IQueryProvider wrapped, Action<T> postProcessor)
        {
            _wrapped = wrapped;
            _postProcessor = postProcessor;
        }

        public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
        {
            return _wrapped.CreateQuery(expression);
        }

        public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
        {
            return _wrapped.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression);
        }

        public object Execute(Expression expression)
        {
            var result = _wrapped.Execute(expression);
            var asT = result as T;
            if (asT != null)
                _postProcessor(asT);
            return result;
        }

        public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
        {
            var result = _wrapped.Execute<TResult>(expression);
            var asT = result as T;
            if (asT != null)
                _postProcessor(asT);
            return result;
        }
    }

    // wraps IQueryable.GetEnumerator() with post-processing action
    class QueryableWrapper<T> : IQueryable<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly IQueryable<T> _wrapped;
        private readonly Action<T> _postProcessor;
        private readonly IQueryProvider _provider;

        public QueryableWrapper(IQueryable<T> wrapped, Action<T> postProcessor)
        {
            _wrapped = wrapped;
            _postProcessor = postProcessor;
            _provider = new QueryProviderWrapper<T>(_wrapped.Provider, postProcessor);
        }

        public Expression Expression
        {
            get { return _wrapped.Expression; }
        }

        public Type ElementType
        {
            get { return _wrapped.ElementType; }
        }

        public IQueryProvider Provider
        {
            get { return _provider; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _wrapped
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Do(_postProcessor)
                .GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

The `GetEnumerator()` decorator uses the `.Do()` extension method from [Interactive Extensions](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/07/Ix) which is like a cross between `Select` and `ForEach`: it is lazily invoked, but takes an `Action<T>` and returns `T`